# Creating SQLite database if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying out SQLAlchemy and I am using this connection string:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///C:\\sqlitedbs\\database.db')
```

Does SQLAlchemy create an SQLite database if one is not already present in a directory it was supposed to fetch the database file?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes,sqlalchemy does create a database for you.I confirmed it on windows using this code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///C:\\sqlitedbs\\school.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()


class School(Base):

    __tablename__ = "woot"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)  


    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name    


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: so if the sqlite database is an existing file in that directory that you are pointing at, it will call it up instead? Ie: if it exist, connect to it, else, create it. Am I right to say that?

Comment: Absolutely,i found that to be the case.

Comment: In case others are confused: the file is created during the `create_all(engine)` statement, not during the `create_engine(...)` statement.

Answer (score 17):

As others have posted, SQLAlchemy will do this automatically. I encountered this error, however, when I [didn't use enough slashes!](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlite)

I used `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI="sqlite:///path/to/file.db"` when I should have used four slashes: `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI="sqlite:////path/to/file.db"`

Answer (score 13):

**Linux stored SQLite3 database**

database will be create in the same folder as the .py file:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///school.db', echo=True)
```

will instantiate the school.db file in the same folder as the .py file.

Comment: I need to call engine.connect() to get the db file actually created

Answer (score 8):

I found (using sqlite+pysqlite) that if the directory exists, it will create it, but if the directory does not exist  it throws an exception:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
```

My workaround is to do this, although it feels nasty:

```
    if connection_string.startswith('sqlite'):
        db_file = re.sub("sqlite.*:///", "", connection_string)
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(db_file), exist_ok=True)
    self.engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)
```

Comment: Right, in this case I would probably just print a message to the user that says, "Sorry, I can't create database FOO because directory BAR does not exist." Then, if the user wants to create it and proceed, they can.

Comment: For an interactive app that's fine, but I also want this to work in a continuous integration context

Comment: Once the directories exist, it will work in continuous integration. You have to decide whether the missing directory is an error and requires user intervention (in which case you generate a error message and give up) or whether a missing directory is just a warning or minor exception in which case you create (possibly a whole chain of) directories and carry on, which, as you say, is 'nasty'. Or you make it configurable...

Comment: by "make it configurable", I mean provide a config setting where the user can say 'create any missing directories without bothering me about it' or 'let me know if directories are missing and I'll create them for you.'

Answer (score 4):

[@Gandolf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16285333/10415970) was good.

The database is created it when you make any connection with your engine.

Here's an example of doing nothing with a database besides connecting to it, and this will create the database.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database.db')

with engine.connect() as conn:
    pass
```

Without the `engine.connect()` or some form of `metadata.create_all()` the database will not be created.