# Cannot create database with SQLAlchemy with SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Please note that I have been attempting to create a new database using SQLAlchemy, but have gotten many errors where I am attempting to work with laravel and vagrant.  Thankfully I have been able to create a new database using pyodbc, but ultimately I would like to do everything through SQLAlchemy.

This is the code that works for creating a new database at this point using pyodbc:

```
    for tagList in myTagList:
        conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=localhost,2433; database=master; UID=myUser;PWD=myUser2", autocommit=True) 
        conn.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + tagList["job"].jobNumber)
```

How would I change this to work with SQLAlchemy?  Presently I have looked at many links like [How to create a new database using SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506578/how-to-create-a-new-database-using-sqlalchemy) and [sqlalchemy,creating an sqlite database if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284537/sqlalchemy-creating-an-sqlite-database-if-it-doesnt-exist) but and https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database_helpers.html it appears to work with postgresql but not SQL Server:

Add support for creating databases (see [How to create a new database using SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506578/how-to-create-a-new-database-using-sqlalchemy)):

```
Projects>pip install sqlalchemy-utils
pip install sqlalchemy-utils
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won`t be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting sqlalchemy-utils
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/7e/3211ad9b3983b216d1b1863fd7734f80bacd1a62a5de8ff6844fb5ed1498/SQLAlchemy-Utils-0.35.0.tar.gz (129kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\myUser\appdata\roaming\python\python27\site-packages (from sqlalchemy-utils) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy>=1.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from sqlalchemy-utils) (1.3.11)
Installing collected packages: sqlalchemy-utils
    Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy-utils: started
    Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy-utils: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed sqlalchemy-utils-0.35.0

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Save historical data into new MyDB000N database
for tagList in myTagList:
    fsDatabaseEngine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://myUser:myUser2@localhost:2433/' + tagList["job"].jobNumber + '?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes')
    if not database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url):
        create_database(fsDatabaseEngine.url)
    print(database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url))

-----
```

On this line `if not database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url):` receiving:

```
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 482, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('28000', u'[28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user \'myUser\'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "MyDB00001" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user \'myUser\'. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "MyDB00001" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

-----

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\connectors\pyodbc.py:79: SAWarning: No driver name specified; this is expected by PyODBC when using DSN-less connections
  "No driver name specified; "

-----

#Save historical data into new MyDB000N database
for tagList in myTagList:
    # fsDatabaseEngine = create_engine('mssql://mssql@localhost:2433/' + tagList["job"].jobNumber + '?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes')
    # if not database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url):
    create_database('mssql://mssql@localhost:2433/' + tagList["job"].jobNumber)
    #print(database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url))

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 482, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', u'[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
PS Projects>

-----

#Save historical data into new MyDB000N database
for tagList in myTagList:
    # fsDatabaseEngine = create_engine('mssql://mssql@localhost:2433/' + tagList["job"].jobNumber + '?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes')
    # if not database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url):
    create_database('mssql://myUser:myUser2@localhost:2433/' + tagList["job"].jobNumber+ '?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes')
    #print(database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url))

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 581, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', u'[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction. (226) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: CREATE DATABASE [MyDB00001]]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
PS Projects>

-----

#Save historical data into new MyDB000N database
for tagList in myTagList:
    with create_engine(
        'mssql://mssql',
        isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT"
        ).connect() as connection:
            connection.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + tagList["job"].jobNumber)
    # if not database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url):
    #create_database('mssql://myUser:myUser2@localhost:2433/' + tagList["job"].jobNumber)
    #print(database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url))

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 482, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', u'[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
PS Projects>

-----

#Save historical data into new MyDB000N database
for tagList in myTagList:
    session.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + tagList["job"].jobNumber)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 581, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', u'[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction. (226) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: CREATE DATABASE MyDB00001]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
PS Projects>

-----

#Save historical data into new MyDB000N database
for tagList in myTagList:
    conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server};server=ubuntu-bionic; database=master; trusted_connection=true",
                      autocommit=True)

Exception has occurred: OperationalError
('08001', u'[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)')
  File "Projects\interesting_data.py", line 81, in <module>
    autocommit=True)

-----

#Save historical data into new MyDB000N database
for tagList in myTagList:
    conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};server=localhost,2433; database=master; trusted_connection=true", autocommit=True)

Exception has occurred: InterfaceError
('IM002', u'[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
  File "Projects\interesting_data.py", line 80, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};server=localhost,2433; database=master; trusted_connection=true", autocommit=True)

-----    

#Save historical data into new MyDB000N database
for tagList in myTagList:
    conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=localhost,2433; database=master; trusted_connection=true", autocommit=True)

Exception has occurred: OperationalError
('08001', u"[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid value specified for connection string attribute 'trusted_connection' (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
  File "Projects\interesting_data.py", line 80, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=localhost,2433; database=master; trusted_connection=true", autocommit=True)

-----

#Save historical data into new MyDB000N database
for tagList in myTagList:
    conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=localhost,2433; database=master; trusted_connection=yes", autocommit=True)

Exception has occurred: Error
('HY000', u'[HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: No credentials are available in the security package\r\n (-2146893042) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Cannot generate SSPI context (-2146893042); [HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: No credentials are available in the security package\r\n (-2146893042); [HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Cannot generate SSPI context (-2146893042)')
  File "Projects\interesting_data.py", line 80, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=localhost,2433; database=master; trusted_connection=yes", autocommit=True)
```

---

```
import urllib

#Save historical data into new MyDB000N database
for tagList in rdTagList:
    # if not database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url):
    params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=localhost,2433; database=master; UID=phpUser;PWD=phpUser2")
    tagListEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
    tagListEngine.connect()
```

Which gives:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'module' object has no attribute 'parse'
  File "C:\Projects\interesting_data.py", line 82, in <module>
    params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=localhost,2433; database=master; UID=myUser;PWD=myUser2")
```

What do you suggest?  TIA.

**UPDATE:**

Not sure how I missed it before but ultimately based on [@snakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb)'s suggestion it is now working without requiring `urllib`:

```
#Save historical data into new MyDB000N database
for tagList in rdTagList:
    fsDatabaseEngine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://myUser:myUser2@localhost:2433/' + tagList["job"].jobNumber + '?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes')
    if not database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url):
        create_database(fsDatabaseEngine.url)
    print(database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url))
```

Thank you!

**UPDATE 2:**

To zero in on the solution, in my research I had found explanations using `postgres://postgres` ..., but ultimately in my case I needed to change `mssql://myUser` to `mssql+pyodbc://myUser...`

Comment: `conn.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + tagList["job"].jobNumber)` that's statement is really open to injection. If you need to create a database, you should pass parameters and use a dynamic statement with `QUOTENAME`: `DECLARE @Create nvarchar(275); SET @Create = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@Db) + N';'; EXEC sp_executesql @Create;`

Comment: The tagList["job"].jobNumber is something I have gotten from elsewhere in the python script so I don't see how it is open to SQL injection since these are values I have obtained from the local database.  Also, you are showing me how to solve the injection problem in SQL but not in python which is not helpful.

Comment: If you `print(fsDatabaseEngine.url)` is it the correct connection string?  The error message indicates that either the log in credentials or the database name must be wrong.

Comment: Okay I'm not not sure how I missed that--it is suddenly working now!.  If I print the print(fsDatabaseEngine.url) it gives me the correct connection string.  If you post that @snakecharmerb I will mark it as the answer.  Thank you!

Comment: It *is* helpful, @user8128167 , as syntax such as "CREATE DATABASE @Parameter;` isn't valid syntax, and I *assume* you know how to parametrise a Python SQL statement. The fact that you were insecurely injecting said the me you didn't know how to safely inject.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Larnu.  I am aware of SQL injection and thought it didn't really apply since I was getting the data myself locally in the python script, but in general I see that it is a bad habit.  In the future I will use SQL parameters instead of adding arguments using '+' with strings to help prevent the possibility of SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [@shakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb)'s comment, this is the solution:

```py
# Save historical data into new MyDB000N database
for tagList in rdTagList:
    fsDatabaseEngine = create_engine(
        'mssql+pyodbc://myUser:myUser2@localhost:2433/' +
        tagList["job"].jobNumber +
        '?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes'
    )
    if not database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url):
        create_database(fsDatabaseEngine.url)
    print(database_exists(fsDatabaseEngine.url))
```