# Get data from an existing database in Flask Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, flask-login

I have a pre coded Sql Alchemy database  and the file name is app.db , I wold like to use the same app to get those data to code a fresh flask app , If so how can i do it?

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,current_app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']="sqlite:///app .db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/')
def home_page():

    return render_template('index.html')
```

When I run the above code in my Flask app it creates a new db file but I want to get data from the app.db file which I have already created

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the code you used to create app.db, and the flask code you're trying to access it with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated the code I  used as it is specified in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra space in `app .db` in this line `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']="sqlite:///app .db"`, I think you need to remove this to get your code working.

Answer (score 0):

here, you should add the absolute path to this file right.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']="sqlite:///absolute path"
```

like in the engine of SQLQLCHEMY here

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///C:\\sqlitedbs\\app.db', echo=True)
```

I guess the sample here helps:
[sqlalchemy,creating an sqlite database if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284537/sqlalchemy-creating-an-sqlite-database-if-it-doesnt-exist)